# How do I change the colored bar of a selected cell in a notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter

Can anyone tell me how I change the color of this blue bar denoting the currently selected cell of a jupyter notebook?

[image: this blue bar]

I tried changing a bunch of the "workbench.colorCustomizations" options (including all the "notebook.something" options) but none of them seem to affect this color.

For example, I tried adding the following to my settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "notebook.cellToolbarSeparator":   "#991212", 
    "notebook.focusedCellBackground":  "#991212", 
    "notebook.cellHoverBackground":  "#991212", 
    "notebook.focusedCellBorder":   "#991212"
}
```

I also tried many other options without results.

Answer (score 0):

Some settings must have been added after this question:

```
"notebook.focusedCellBorder": "#ff0000",
"notebook.focusedCellBorder": "#ff0000",
"notebook.focusedCellBackground": "#ff0000",

"notebook.inactiveFocusedCellBorder": "#ff0000",
```

and for multi-selected cells but the currently inactive though selected cells, see

```
"notebook.inactiveSelectedCellBorder"
```

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_55.md for that last one https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#notebook-colors for all notebook-related colors.